# Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex;

Tags: python, list, recursion

I am trying to write a program to find the sum of a list using recursion in python and my code is this

```
value = 0

def sum_list(alist):
    global value
    if len(alist) == 0:
        return value
    value += alist.pop()
    return sum_list(alist)

print sum_list(range(10))
```

But when i am executing this script I am getting a weired error.

```
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/%{ <-- HERE (.*?)}/ at /usr/bin/print line 528.
Error: no "print" mailcap rules found for type "text/x-python"
```

I searched for it but couldn't get why this error is coming.
Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

Your code is valid Python 2.  (It's not valid Python 3 because the print statement would have to be different.)

You don't say how you are actually running this code, but it looks like it is not actually being interpreted as a Python program.  The error message is coming from /usr/bin/print, so I think you have managed to get this interpreted as a shell script somehow, and the "print" on your final line is running /usr/bin/print.  That's obviously not what you want.

If you are executing this inside a source file, try putting the following line at the top of it, to tell the shell to run this as a Python program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Alternatively, run it using

```
python myfile.py
```

Comment: i just got this error too. but what i found out is that i wrote `print file.py` instead of `python file.py`. lack of coffee...

Comment: Just did the same.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem, it was an oversight at the terminal prompt. I was typing `print` instead of `python`

`$ print sum.py`
`$ Error: no "print" mailcap rules found for type "text/x-python"`

**Correct way:**

`$ python sum.py`
`$ program runs successfully...`

Answer (score -1):

The error message comes from Perl. No idea how you managed to call it with this Python code.

---

###### 6 years later ...

As it turned out did the OP call `print` instead of `python` (look into the error message)

And `/usr/bin/print` is a Perl script, at least on Ubuntu.